# When I point a pointer to an array. Why does the pointer and the index[0] of the array I am pointing to have different memory addresses?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int arr[5];
arr[0] = 10;
arr[1] = 20;
arr[2] = 30;
arr[3] = 40;
arr[4] = 50;

int *p = &arr;

printf("Memory address of first index: %p\n", &arr[0]);
printf("Memory address of pointer: %p\n", &p);

return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT
Memory address of first index: 000000000061FE00
Memory address of pointer: 000000000061FDF8

They are are not the same. Is my machine bad?

Comment: The address *of* the pointer variable `p` is not the same as the address stored *in* the pointer variable `p`.  Try changing it to `printf("Memory address in pointer: %p\n", p);`.

Comment: Do not use `int *p = &arr;`. Your compiler should be warning you about this. `&arr[0]` is the address of the first `int` in `arr`; its type is `int *`. But `&arr` is the address of the entire array. It is the same address in memory as the first element, but its type is different; it is `int (*)[5]`, a pointer to an array of 5 elements. When you use it to initialize an `int *`, the compiler should warn you the types do not match.

Comment: *Is my machine bad?* No.  For a programming language as widely used as C, you probably have a better chance of winning the lottery, or being hit by lightning, than you do of discovering a bug in the C compiler, or a flaw in your computer's hardware.  The chances are roughly 99.9999% that there's a problem with the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the compiler should issue a message relative to this declaration

```
int *p = &arr;
```

The problem is that the right hand side expression has the type `int( * )[5]` while the initialized object has the type `int *` and there is no implicit conversion between these two pointer types.

You should write either

```
int *p = arr;
```

In this case the array designator is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element. Or

```
int ( *p )[5] = &arr;
```

The pointer `p` occupies its own extent of memory. So its address  is different from the address of the extent of the memory occupied by the array `arr`.

On the other hand, if you will output the value stored in the pointer `p` like for example

```
printf("Memory address stored in the pointer p: %p\n", ( void * )p);
```

then it will be equal to the address of the first element of the array arr

```
printf("Memory address of first index: %p\n", ( void )&arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr` is an array. It and its elements start at some place in memory.

`p` is a pointer to the array. Its value is an address. That address needs to be stored somewhere else in memory. That place is different from where the array is stored.

`printf("%p\n", (void *) p);` prints the **value** of `p`, which will be the address of `arr` (and of `&arr[0]`, since the first element is at the start of the array).

`printf("%p\n", (void *) &p)` prints the **address** of `p`, which is where `p` is.